# Regex to get fields separated by "="

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I'm doing a `$.getJSON` to retrieve some data and it's giving me back the following:

```
address = 1233 Abc St
address2 = Suite 123
city = San Francisco
state = CA
zip = 12345
```

What I would ideally want is to have this broken into an array like:

```
array['address'] = "1233 Abc St"
array['address2'] = "Suite 123"
...
```

This seems like it would be simple regex, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: Just FYI, that JavaScript syntax doesn't manipulate an *array*, but an `object`. You would be setting properties on an object, not positions in an array (e.g. `{ address: '1233 Abc St', address2: 'Suite 123' }`).

Comment: @Cory What array notation? `array['address']`? It's a perfectly valid way to set properties on an object.

Comment: @Kolink: WHOOPS! You're right. I forgot about that. I edited the comment to clarify a little.

Comment: The problem is because the **object** is called `array`, which is confusing.

Comment: I would've preferred an array, but an object did the job. I used that syntax because I'm used to PHP, so it just seems natural to write arrays like that, I didn't even think that JavaScript didn't have something similar. And, unfortunately, this is the format the API I'm using returns in. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but I have to work with what I'm given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easier done by iteration:

```
var lines = source.split("\n"), l = lines.length, i, out = {}, line;
for(i=0; i<l; i++) {
    line = lines[i].split(/\s+=\s+/);
    out[line[0]] = line[1];
}
```